# Javascript replace function not working with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Why is this code not working as it should?

```
var temp = "@TEMP (A1)"
var text = "1st Oct @TEMP (A1)"
text = text.replace(new RegExp(temp, "gi"), "");
console.log(text); //I get same text even though I used replace instead of 1st Oct??
```

Can anybody explain what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote the special characters of `temp` which is being directly used as your regular expression. The `(` and `)` characters are grouping characters to the pattern, not actually matching '(' and ')'.

Answer (score 4):

Parentheses in regex have special meaning unless escaped:

```
var temp = "@TEMP \\(A1\\)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis serve a special case in regular expressions. Escape them with a backslash. Also you can use forward-slash notation to create a RegExp object instead.

```
var loRegExp = /@TEMP \(A1\)/gi;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = "@TEMP \\(A1\\)";
var text = "1st Oct @TEMP (A1)";
text = text.replace(new RegExp(temp, "gi"), "");
console.log(text);
```

curly parentheses is a special character in Regexp, you should use backslash to escape it.